# MeteorJS the good way to build & access my documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to build an MeteorJS App. This is a kind of playlist manager.

It looks like spotify, There is 3 colums so I made 3 templates,
from left to right :
- The playlists list
- The medias of the selected playlist
- The selected media's details

so here's my code :

server.js

```
Playlists = new Meteor.Collection("playlists");

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function() {
    if (Playlists.find().count() === 0) {
      var names = ["test1",
                   "222",
                   "test3",
                   "444",
                   "test5",
                   "666"];
      for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        Playlists.insert({'name': names[i]});
    }

    return (
      Meteor.methods({
        addPlaylist: function(playlistName) {
          Playlists.insert({'name': playlistName, 'medias': []});
        },
        delPlaylist: function(playlistId) {
          Playlists.remove({'_id': playlistId});
        },
        renPlaylist: function(playlistId, newName) {
          Playlists.update({'_id': playlistId}, {'$set': {'name': newName}});
        },
        addMedia: function(playlistId, newMedia) {
          var current_playlist = Playlists.findOne({'_id': playlistId});
          Playlists.update(current_playlist, {$push: {'medias': newMedia}});
        }
      })
    );
  });

  Playlists.allow({
    insert: function(userId, doc) {
      return (false);
    },
    update: function(userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
      return (false);
    },
    remove: function(userId, doc) {
      return (false);
    }
  });

}
```

my templates :

```
<template name="t_playlistsCol">
  <button id="newPlaylist" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
    New Playlist
  </button>
  <div id="listPlaylist">
    {{#each playlists}}
      <button class="playlist {{Pselected}} btn btn-default" type="button">
        {{name}}
      </button>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="t_mediasCol">
  {{#if current_playlist}}
    <div class="menuPlaylist">
      <img id="playPlaylist" class="btn" src="icon_play1.png">
      <h4>{{current_playlist}}</h4>
      <div id="optionsPlaylist">
        <button id="insertMedia" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
        <button id="renamePlaylist" class="btn btn-info">Rename</button>
        <button id="deletePlaylist" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <table id="listMedias">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="mediaName">Titre</th>
          <th class="mediaType">Type</th>
          <th class="mediaTime">Durée</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {{#each medias}}
          <tr class="media {{Mselected}}">
            <td class="mediaName">{{name}}</td>
            <td class="mediaType">{{type}}</td>
            <td class="mediaTime">{{time}}</td>
          </tr>
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  {{else}}
    <div class="menuPlaylist">
      <h3 id="noPlaylist">Select a playlist</h3>
    </div>
  {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="t_previewCol">
  {{#if current_media}}
    <div class="menuPreview">
      <p>{{current_media}}</p>
    </div>
  {{else}}
    <div class="menuPreview">
      <h3 id="noPreview">Select a media</h3>
    </div>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

client.js :

```
(
Playlists = new Meteor.Collection("playlists");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.t_playlistsCol.playlists = function() {
    return (Playlists.find({}, {sort: {"name": 1}}));
  };

  Template.t_playlistsCol.events = {
    'click #newPlaylist': function() {
      var playlistName = prompt("Nom de la playlist : ");
      if (playlistName) {
        Meteor.call('addPlaylist', playlistName);
      }
    },
    'click .playlist': function() {
      Session.set("selected_playlist", this._id);
    }
  };

  Template.t_playlistsCol.Pselected = function() {
    return ( Session.equals("selected_playlist", this._id) ? "Pselected" : '' );
  };

  Template.t_mediasCol.current_playlist = function() {
    var playlist = Playlists.findOne(Session.get("selected_playlist"));
    return (playlist && playlist.name);
  };

  Template.t_mediasCol.medias = function() {
    var current_playlist = Playlists.findOne(Session.get("selected_playlist"));
    return ( current_playlist.medias );
  };

  Template.t_mediasCol.events = {
    'click #insertMedia': function() {
      var playlistId = Session.get("selected_playlist");
      var newMedia = {
        name: "mediaTest",
        type: "img",
        time: "00:15"
      };
      newMedia._id = new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID();
      Meteor.call('addMedia', playlistId, newMedia);
    },
    'click #deletePlaylist': function() {
      var playlistId = Session.get("selected_playlist");
      Meteor.call('delPlaylist', playlistId);
    },
    'click #renamePlaylist': function() {
      var playlist = Playlists.findOne(Session.get("selected_playlist"));
      var newName = prompt("Renommer " + playlist.name + " en :");
      if (newName) {
        Meteor.call('renPlaylist', playlist._id, newName);
      }
    },
    'click .media': function() {
      Session.set("selected_media", this._id);
    }
  };

  Template.t_mediasCol.Mselected = function() {
    return ( Session.equals("selected_media", this._id) ? "Mselected" : "" );
  };

  Template.t_previewCol.current_media = function() {
    var playlistId = Session.get("selected_playlist");
    var mediaId = Session.get("selected_media");
    var playlist = Playlists.find({'_id': playlistId});
    return(playlist.medias[0] && playlist.medias[0].name);
  };

  Accounts.ui.config({
    passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_ONLY'
  });
}
```

I'm a newbie, I'm learning Meteor for 3 weeks.

**SO, MY PROBLEM** is that, I want the user to be able to select a media and see its details with the template "t_previewCol" .
It works for the playlists, but I don't have what I want with the helper "Template.t_previewCol.current_media", it prints this error when I do a console.log to debug :

```
Exception in template helper:
Template.t_previewCol.current_media@http://localhost:3000/client
/client.js?7212665c7dc29cf721272fa4cabeb499f2e18bf5:69:5
bindToCurrentDataIfIsFunction/<@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:2448:7
Blaze.wrapCatchingExceptions/<@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1552:7
Spacebars.call@http://localhost:3000/packages
/spacebars.js?8717c3bee1160f47e7a46ea4e1bd0796f944cad8:169:5
@http://localhost:3000/client
/template.client.js?d2b9a924f64621cd0bcfc1292538f5b63523959a:117:5
Blaze.If/</<@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:2275:11
viewAutorun/<@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1805:7
Blaze.withCurrentView@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:2038:5
viewAutorun@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1804:5
Deps.Computation.prototype._compute@http://localhost:3000/packages
/deps.js?d9b2b2601bdab0f57291b38e7974a7190b8aac01:214:5
Deps.Computation@http://localhost:3000/packages
/deps.js?d9b2b2601bdab0f57291b38e7974a7190b8aac01:148:5
Deps.autorun@http://localhost:3000/packages
/deps.js?d9b2b2601bdab0f57291b38e7974a7190b8aac01:362:7
Blaze.View.prototype.autorun@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1803:7
Blaze.If/<@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:2277:1
fireCallbacks@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1818:9
Deps.nonreactive@http://localhost:3000/packages
/deps.js?d9b2b2601bdab0f57291b38e7974a7190b8aac01:382:5
Blaze._fireCallbacks/<@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1815:5
Blaze.withCurrentView@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:2038:5
Blaze._fireCallbacks@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1814:3
Blaze.materializeView@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1830:3
.visitObject@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1458:7
.visit@http://localhost:3000/packages
/htmljs.js?fcf2660be84fbc0c33b97ee8932dbd46612f3566:116:7
doMaterialize@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1862:13
Deps.nonreactive@http://localhost:3000/packages
/deps.js?d9b2b2601bdab0f57291b38e7974a7190b8aac01:382:5
doRender@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1860:7
viewAutorun/<@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1805:7
Blaze.withCurrentView@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:2038:5
viewAutorun@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1804:5
Deps.Computation.prototype._compute@http://localhost:3000/packages
/deps.js?d9b2b2601bdab0f57291b38e7974a7190b8aac01:214:5
Deps.Computation@http://localhost:3000/packages
/deps.js?d9b2b2601bdab0f57291b38e7974a7190b8aac01:148:5
Deps.autorun@http://localhost:3000/packages
/deps.js?d9b2b2601bdab0f57291b38e7974a7190b8aac01:362:7
Blaze.View.prototype.autorun@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1803:7
Blaze.materializeView/<@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1851:5
Deps.nonreactive@http://localhost:3000/packages
/deps.js?d9b2b2601bdab0f57291b38e7974a7190b8aac01:382:5
Blaze.materializeView@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1850:3
.visitObject@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1458:7
.visit@http://localhost:3000/packages
/htmljs.js?fcf2660be84fbc0c33b97ee8932dbd46612f3566:116:7
.visitArray@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1363:7
.visit@http://localhost:3000/packages
/htmljs.js?fcf2660be84fbc0c33b97ee8932dbd46612f3566:114:9
.visitTag@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1441:9
.visit@http://localhost:3000/packages
/htmljs.js?fcf2660be84fbc0c33b97ee8932dbd46612f3566:101:11
.visitArray@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1363:7
.visit@http://localhost:3000/packages
/htmljs.js?fcf2660be84fbc0c33b97ee8932dbd46612f3566:114:9
.visitTag@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1441:9
.visit@http://localhost:3000/packages
/htmljs.js?fcf2660be84fbc0c33b97ee8932dbd46612f3566:101:11
.visitArray@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1363:7
.visit@http://localhost:3000/packages
/htmljs.js?fcf2660be84fbc0c33b97ee8932dbd46612f3566:114:9
doMaterialize@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1862:13
Deps.nonreactive@http://localhost:3000/packages
/deps.js?d9b2b2601bdab0f57291b38e7974a7190b8aac01:382:5
doRender@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1860:7
viewAutorun/<@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1805:7
Blaze.withCurrentView@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:2038:5
viewAutorun@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1804:5
Deps.Computation.prototype._compute@http://localhost:3000/packages
/deps.js?d9b2b2601bdab0f57291b38e7974a7190b8aac01:214:5
Deps.Computation@http://localhost:3000/packages
/deps.js?d9b2b2601bdab0f57291b38e7974a7190b8aac01:148:5
Deps.autorun@http://localhost:3000/packages
/deps.js?d9b2b2601bdab0f57291b38e7974a7190b8aac01:362:7
Blaze.View.prototype.autorun@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1803:7
Blaze.materializeView/<@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1851:5
Deps.nonreactive@http://localhost:3000/packages
/deps.js?d9b2b2601bdab0f57291b38e7974a7190b8aac01:382:5
Blaze.materializeView@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1850:3
.visitObject@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1458:7
.visit@http://localhost:3000/packages
/htmljs.js?fcf2660be84fbc0c33b97ee8932dbd46612f3566:116:7
.visitArray@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1363:7
.visit@http://localhost:3000/packages
/htmljs.js?fcf2660be84fbc0c33b97ee8932dbd46612f3566:114:9
doMaterialize@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1862:13
Deps.nonreactive@http://localhost:3000/packages
/deps.js?d9b2b2601bdab0f57291b38e7974a7190b8aac01:382:5
doRender@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1860:7
viewAutorun/<@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1805:7
Blaze.withCurrentView@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:2038:5
viewAutorun@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1804:5
Deps.Computation.prototype._compute@http://localhost:3000/packages
/deps.js?d9b2b2601bdab0f57291b38e7974a7190b8aac01:214:5
Deps.Computation@http://localhost:3000/packages
/deps.js?d9b2b2601bdab0f57291b38e7974a7190b8aac01:148:5
Deps.autorun@http://localhost:3000/packages
/deps.js?d9b2b2601bdab0f57291b38e7974a7190b8aac01:362:7
Blaze.View.prototype.autorun@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1803:7
Blaze.materializeView/<@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1851:5
Deps.nonreactive@http://localhost:3000/packages
/deps.js?d9b2b2601bdab0f57291b38e7974a7190b8aac01:382:5
Blaze.materializeView@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:1850:3
Blaze.render@http://localhost:3000/packages
/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:2068:3
instantiateBody@http://localhost:3000/packages
/templating.js?e2c0d3bbe4292a0b20c3083eaf4fcd0f5f91bb52:245:7
ready@http://localhost:3000/packages
/meteor.js?7a66be7a03504cd2c18dd47b699e6233b60675ed:641:6
```

Perhaps its because of way I built my documents, they look like that :

```
{
  _id: "idP",
  name: "nameP",
  medias: [
    {
      _id: "idM1",
      name: "nameM1"
    },
    {
      _id: "idM2",
      name: "nameM2"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I tried to give you a maximum of details about my problem, I hope someone could help me.

thanks.

**EDIT :**
I have fixed the behavior of my "preview column" when the user click on a media

```
Template.t_previewCol.current_media = function() {
var playlistId = Session.get("selected_playlist");
var mediaId = Session.get("selected_media");
var playlist = Playlists.findOne({'_id': playlistId});
for (var i = 0 ; i < playlist.medias.length ; ++i)
  if (playlist.medias[i]._id._str === mediaId._str)
    return(playlist.medias[i] && playlist.medias[i].name);
return (null);
};
```

I was trying to do

```
if (playlist.medias[i]._id === mediaId)
```

but since I've assigned the medias._id using Meteor.Collection.ObjectId() it was not working.

Now I just want to understand what is the error I pasted above.

Answer (score 0):

`Playlists.find` returns a cursor. I think that you want `Playlists.findOne`.

```
  Template.t_previewCol.current_media = function() {
    var playlistId = Session.get("selected_playlist");
    var mediaId = Session.get("selected_media");
    var playlist = Playlists.findOne({'_id': playlistId});
    return(playlist.medias[0] && playlist.medias[0].name);
  };
```

Comment: Yep you are right, it was just a little forget. But the same error remains.